# ResultSet showing empty but there is at least 1 record in the table

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

**ISSUE**  My ResultSet is empty but I know there is at least 1 record in the table ("tblStudents")?

**CODE** :

```
package smartdatabase;

/**
 *
 * @author travi
 */
import java.sql.*;

public class Conn {

    private Connection connect = null;
    private Statement stmt = null;

    public Conn() {
    }

    public void getStudents() {
        try {

            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/SmartData", "root", 
"password");
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT FirstName, Surname FROM tblStudents";
            stmt = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            if (rs.next()) {
                String Firstname = rs.getString("Firstname");
                String Surname = rs.getString("surname");
                System.out.println(Firstname + "    " + Surname);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Empty ResultSet");
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried checking the case sensitivity and it doesn't seem to be the issue.

I also tried `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);` and it didn't change anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rs.next()` method will move the pointer of the current object to the next row.

So when you place the condition  `if (rs.next())` the pointer is pointing to the next row only which is null as you have said you have one row entry in the DB.

On calling the next() method for the first time the result set pointer/cursor will be moved to the 1st row. Again calling the next() method for the second time the result set cursor will be moved to the 2nd row. By this way it goes.

You can call the `first() or beforeFirst()`  methods to reset the ResultSet cursor back to the first row.

You can find more explanation at : [ResultSet---isBeforeFirst()---AND--first()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst--)

Now for checking empty you need to implement in the below way, move the cursor to the first position, it will return false if the result set is empty:

**Option 1 :**

```
  if (!rs.first()) {
      System.out.println("Empty ResultSet");
  } else {
      do {
          String Firstname = rs.getString("Firstname");
          String Surname = rs.getString("surname");
          System.out.println(Firstname + "    " + Surname);
      } while (rs.next());
  }
```

***UPDATE :***

**Option 2 :**

```
if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {    
    System.out.println("Empty ResultSet"); 
} else {
      do {
          String Firstname = rs.getString("Firstname");
          String Surname = rs.getString("surname");
          System.out.println(Firstname + "    " + Surname);
      } while (rs.next());
}
```

**Option 3 :**

```
if (!rs.isBeforeFirst() && rs.getRow() == 0) {    
    System.out.println("Empty ResultSet"); 
} else {
      do {
          String Firstname = rs.getString("Firstname");
          String Surname = rs.getString("surname");
          System.out.println(Firstname + "    " + Surname);
      } while (rs.next());
}
```

***UPDATE 2 :***

For DERBY database use the below parameters in `createStatement`:

```
// Replace : stmt = connect.createStatement();
stmt = connect.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
                               ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Then use the above **option 1** mentioned.

Comment: I tried your code, and I still have the same output happening

Comment: @Travopticat : It will be `rs.first()` . I have updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: another eorror "This method should only be called on ResultSet objects t hat are scrollable"

Comment: @Travopticat : Which DB you are using ? Methods `rs.first()`  or `rs.beforeFirst()` may not work always.

Comment: @Travopticat : have you tried the Option 2 in the answer.

Comment: @Travopticat : Try Option 2/3 .. it should be working. These are the only ways to check for empty resultset.

Comment: I am using a Derby database (embedded in Netbeans)

Comment: @Travopticat  Ohhk .. for DERBY db I have added an option.. can u pls use that. `Update 2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220783/discussion-between-travopticat-and-som).